# Regex help pls for extracting values with quotes

Tags: c#, regex, express

I've been trying to create a RegEx for a string for almost a day and still haven't made it work, can anyone help?

```
string example (double quotes are options, and can also be single quotes):
    "234"? "<img src=\"http://abc.com/a.jpg\" onclick=\"alert(\"\"working with 'quotes'?\"\");\" />"

and the following groups should be extracted:
    234
    <img src="http://abc.com/a.jpg" onclick="alert(""working with 'quotes'?"");" />
```

hope this is clear, anyone help pls!!

Comment: between the separator "?"  spaces is allowed

Comment: for the first part and later parts separated by "?";  double quotes are optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the efficiency of this regex, but here is one that matched your string.

**Rules**

1. Quotes around number are optional, and can be single-quotes.
2. Quotes around html are optional, and can be single-quotes.
3. Space(s) after question mark can be 0 or many.

**Input**

```
"234"? "<img src=\"http://abc.com/a.jpg\" onclick=\"alert(\"\"working with 'quotes'?\"\");\" />"
```

**Regex**

```
^['"]?(?<number>\d+)['"]?\?\s*['"]?(?<html>\<.*\>)['"]?$
```

**Output Groups**

```
number: 234
html: <img src=\"http://abc.com/a.jpg\" onclick=\"alert(\"\"working with 'quotes'?\"\");\" />
```

Comment: I hope this is helps.  Sorry, I didn't find your question to be very descriptive of the requirements.

Comment: I'm afraid your regexp will fail if you add another tag (<>) to the string - it will match everything between the first < and the last >.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - the user said he wanted just 2 groups.  So yes, so if you add additional '<>' chars it will still be matched in the 'html' group.  The question was vague but I think that was desired. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick solution (in JavaScript):

```
var s = "\"234\"? \"<img src=\"http://abc.com/a.jpg\" onclick=\"alert(\"\"working with 'quotes'?\"\");\" />\"";
var matches = s.match(/['"][\d]*['"](?=[\s]*\?)|['"]<[^><]*>['"]/ig);
```

The first part `['"][\d]*['"](?=[\s]*\?)` matches numbers inside quotes followed by optional spaces and ?.
The second part `['"]<[^><]*>['"]` matches any symbols (except <, >) inside quotes and <>.

One drawback of this solution is that matched results are wrapped in quotes.
Hope it helps you implement what you need.